# Maven Embedded Glassfish Plugin - not starting

Tags: maven-2, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, glassfish-embedded

I can't seem to get a web application running with the embedded glassfish plugin:

Plugin Configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>${http.port}</port>

                    <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                    <app>${project.build.directory}/${maven.war.final.name}</app>
                    <containerType>web</containerType>
                    <!--
                    <goalPrefix>glassfish</goalPrefix>

                    <configFile>${project.build.directory}/${finalName}/WEB-INF/domain.xml</configFile>

                    <instanceRoot>${project.build.directory}/glassfish/${glassfish.version}</instanceRoot>
                    <installRoot>${project.build.directory}/glassfish/${glassfish.version}</installRoot>
                    -->

                    <!--
                    <contextRoot>test</contextRoot>
                    -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Configuration:

```
<properties>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <maven.war.final.name>${finalName}.war</maven.war.final.name>
        <http.port>80</http.port>
        <glassfish.version>3.0</glassfish.version>
    </properties>
```

Command Line:

```
mvn clean package embedded-glassfish:run
```

Output:

```
INFO: GlassFish v3 (74.2) startup time : Embedded(323ms) startup services(323ms) total(646ms)
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:10 PM com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified initDelegates
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate as the delegate
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:11 PM org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread run
INFO: JMXStartupService: JMXConnector system is disabled, skipping.
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:11 PM AppServerStartup run
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] started
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:11 PM org.hibernate.validator.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Validator null
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:11 PM org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver detectJPA
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:16 PM com.sun.common.util.logging.LoggingConfigImpl openPropFile
INFO: Cannot read logging.properties file. 
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer createHttpListener
INFO: Created HTTP listener embedded-listener on port 80
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer configureHttpServiceProperties
WARNING: pewebcontainer.invalid_http_service_property
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer createHosts
INFO: Created virtual server server
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:16 PM com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer loadSystemDefaultWebModules
INFO: Virtual server server loaded system default web module
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityLifecycle <init>
INFO: security.secmgroff
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.SSLUtils checkCertificateDates
SEVERE: java_security.expired_certificate
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityLifecycle onInitialization
INFO: Security startup service called
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.security.PolicyLoader loadPolicy
INFO: policy.loading
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.Realm doInstantiate
INFO: Realm admin-realm of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm successfully created.
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.Realm doInstantiate
INFO: Realm file of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm successfully created.
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.Realm doInstantiate
INFO: Realm certificate of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm successfully created.
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:18 PM com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityLifecycle onInitialization
INFO: Security service(s) started successfully....
classLoader = WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)
SharedSecrets.getJavaNetAccess()=java.net.URLClassLoader$7@756095fc
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:20 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900 SNAPSHOT
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:20 PM org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver detectJPA
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
nullID: /mnt/projects/github.com/prettyfaces-tests/gfembed4134153095470013496tmp/applications/prettyfaces-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ CLASSES: [class de.chkal.prettytest.WelcomeBean, class de.chkal.prettytest.GreetingBean, class de.chkal.prettytest.WelcomeBean2]

Aug 21, 2010 2:04:20 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10) for context '/prettyfaces-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
Aug 21, 2010 2:04:22 PM com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start
INFO: Loading application prettyfaces-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT at /prettyfaces-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Hit ENTER to redeploy, X to exit
```

Netstat -an | grep 80 doesn't list anything:

```
netstat -an | grep :80
```

This configuration has worked for me in the past, I don't see any log messages or exceptions.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the full explanation (and I'm too lazy to find the real cause of the problem tonight) but it seems the `maven-glassfish-embedded-plugin` doesn't like the port `80`, it just works with, say, `8080`.

By the way, I'd recommend using the version 3.0.1.

```
<properties>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <maven.war.final.name>${finalName}.war</maven.war.final.name>
    <http.port>8080</http.port>
    <glassfish.version>3.0.1</glassfish.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Cool, I will check that now.  I guess that makes sense, I'm running on linux, there are ports below a certain number that are privileged and require superuser to listen on those ports.  That might be within that range, lemme try 8080.

Comment: Sweet, that was it.  I'll try to keep this in mind when using port 80 in the future.

Comment: @Walter That must be it, ports below 1024 require root privilege. I should have thought it was because of this.